# chart.js label with if statement

Tags: javascript, chart.js

for traduction purposes, I am trying to set up my chart.js labels based on html tag text. Being a beginner to javascript, this a bit of a challenge.

Here is what I am trying to do:

html code:

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div id='tag4' class="card-footer small text-muted">{% trans 'ITEMS IN DIFFICULTY' %}</div>
  <div class="bar-chart block">
    <canvas id="myChart3" height="175"></canvas>
  </div>
```

and my chart.js code:

```js
var myChart3 = new Chart(ctx3, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels3,
    datasets: [{
      label: if (document.getElementById('tag4').value == 'ITEMS IN DIFFICULTY') {
        'low performing items (quantity sold/week)'
      }
      else {
        'references en difficulté (quantité vendu/semaine)'
      },
      data: defaultData3,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }],
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        }],
      }
    }
  }
})
```

the result is that the graph does not show up. I am not sure if the issue is because there is something wrong with my if statement or if its not something that can be done with chart.js labels. Any help is more than welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a ternary operator, it works like this:

```js
let isTrue = true
let a = isTrue ? 1 : 0
```

if `isTrue` is true, then `a` is 1, if false, `a` is 0

In your case, you can pass following as a label:

```js
document.getElementById('tag4').textContent == 'ITEMS IN DIFFICULTY' ? 'label if true' : 'label if false'
```

Comment: Thank you! almost working, the graphs shows up but it always output the label as if the text in the div tag was not matching. Do you think it could come from the trans thingie?

Comment: Oh, right. I missed that you had a bug, you need to replace `value` with `textContent`, since you're using `div` and not `input`. I edited my answer with the right code

Comment: that works perfect. I guess ```value``` would be used if there was numbers

Comment: Value is a property of `input` element, the `div` element does not have it. The `input` element can also have text as input in which case the `input` element would give text, so it's not restricted to numbers.